# past perfect VS past tense

Tags: tense

Here's the context.

> Even though it was late May, it was still a bit chilly outside. We lived less than a mile from the Atlantic Ocean, so the coastal breeze was often cool and salty. ***But lately, the skies had been windier than usual.***

Why not were but had been here?

What if I say ***"But lately, the skies were windier than usual"***

I have no idea what is difference.

Answer (score 2):

Even though it **was** late May, it **was** still a bit chilly outside. We **lived** less than a mile from the Atlantic Ocean, so the coastal breeze **was** often cool and salty. But lately, the skies **had been windier** than usual.

The entire paragraph is in the simple past tense starting in late May. **So anything before that point in time and up to that point would use the past perfect.**

/**had been___________________/**late May** _**[simple past]_______now or present.

In other words, until late May,the weather had been windier than usual.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that the phase from the text (with *Past Perfect*) clearly puts '**lately**' to the *past*, where all the events of the narrative take place. '**Lately**' is *earlier* than something the author plans to describe from that point, still using *Past Indefinite*, while in case of the Past Indefinite there would be a possibility for a reader to suppose that the author makes a *digression* (with that 'lately') to the *moment of writing*.