# Past perfect saw thought

Tags: past-perfect

1 I saw you ate

2 I saw you had eaten

3 I thought you were right

4 I thought you had been right

1 and 2 are clear to me. 1 at the same time 2 first eating then seeing for example crumbles. What about 3 and 4. 3 at the same time and 4 first being right and then thinking. It doesn't make sense to me. I think that I need to add something like "I thought you were/ had been right when I saw you". Why is that that when it comes to 1 and 2 I don't need to add anything but with 3 and 4 I have to.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [past perfect VS past tense](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/181020/past-perfect-vs-past-tense)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When is the past perfect exactly needed?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/6372/when-is-the-past-perfect-exactly-needed)

Answer (score 0):

The "past perfect" is used when the speaker is viewing events from a later (but still past) point in time. Sometimes that later point in time will be associated with a specific word ("saw" and "thought" in your examples) but sometimes it will not: it will already have been established in the discourse or (particularly in narrative) it may not have been mentioned but the use of the past perfect itself established a temporal viewpoint. (For example, a story might begin "He had been a moody child" - this establishes that the temporal viewpoint is later, when he was no longer a child, or no longer moody).

So your fourth example is fine as it is: the thinking takes place at a later time than the being right.

It's also worth noting that the use of this complex form is usually optional: English speakers often don't use it when the temporal relationships are obvious, or are unimportant. So your 1 and 2 could refer to precisely the same set of events, and similarly your 3 and 4.

Comment: It amazes me how many times we have to repeat, the past perfect is preceded in time by a verb in another past tense, usually simple past, stated or implied. "I thought you had been right" implies an earlier thing like: when I first **heard the story**.

Comment: I do know that Lambie. I try to say that it is weird to me that when I say I saw she had eaten I do not need to add anything and nothing has to be implied but with my second example I thought you had been right it seems to be that we don't say before thinking but before another event stated or implied

Comment: I saw she had eaten. Here I show that she ate first. I thought you had been right here we don't show that first was being right and then thinking bit we add anothen event. That's why I stuggle with that

Comment: "I thought you had been right" is only credible if the current "narrative focus" is *some point in past time when you changed your mind*. I *don't* find it credible if the speaker has only *just* changed his mind - in that case, he should say "I thought you **were** right". And don't get me started on "I **had** thought you had been right" - anyone who thinks they're still *learning* English should never waste time on such a pointlessly convoluted usage.